# Flutter Boton al lado del texto en Card

Tags: flutter, ios, dart

Estoy haciendo un Card en donde le he metido en el **Paddin: 2 Text y 1 ButtonBar**.
Mi **padding** del card es este:

```
Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 15, top: 5, right: 0, bottom: 0),
          child: Column(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
             children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                   'A partir de',
                   style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                   ),
                ),
                Text(
                   '2,54 €',
                   style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.pink, fontSize: 20
                   ),
                ),
                ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                     children: [
                        FlatButton(
                           color: Colors.yellow,
                              child: 
                                 Text('+'),
                                 shape: CircleBorder(),
                                 textColor: Colors.white,
                                 onPressed: () {},
                         ),
                      ],
                 )
             ],
        ),
),
```

Y me sale el error del tamaño:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que yo quiero es que me salga así, con el **boton del + al lado del texto**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es un layout horizontal abajo del `Text`, así :

```dart
Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 15, top: 5, right: 0, bottom: 0),
          child: Column(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
             children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                   'A partir de',
                   style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                   ),
                ),
               Row(
                children: [
                Text(
                   '2,54 €',
                   style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.pink, fontSize: 20
                   ),
                ),
                ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                     children: [
                        FlatButton(
                           color: Colors.yellow,
                              child: 
                                 Text('+'),
                                 shape: CircleBorder(),
                                 textColor: Colors.white,
                                 onPressed: () {},
                         ),
                      ],
                 ),],)
             ],
        ),
),
```

Te recomiendo que leas la documentación oficial, ahí explican muy bien: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout